# Define a string with html code

Tags: c, string

I want to define a string like in C:

```
String s [] ="(head)(meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" )(/head)";
```

I changed <> to (), just to see it.

Is there a better to to put a html code in a String?

Comment: you can escape the " character like this : \"

Comment: Are you sure you're programming in C? C doesn't have `String`.

Comment: the problem is I had 2 times of   "" within a string,

Comment: I had #include <string.h>

Comment: In that case you need to go back and read a beginners book or tutorial on C, because any decent such book or tutorial should have thought you how to escape special characters in strings. And C *still* doesn't have anything like `String`. When posting code in questions here on SO, please post *real* code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the alternative single quote marks like this

```
char s [] ="<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1' ></head>";
```

and you can use `'<'` and `'>'` in C strings harmlessly.

Comment: Why don't you try it? It's just a few seconds with a text editor. Using the acceptable alternative single-quote `'` is less clumsy and more readable than escaping the `"` double-quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can either an escape character `\`

```
 String s [] ="(head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\" ></head)";
```

Or you can use `'`:

```
 String s [] ="(head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1' ></head)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s [] ="(head)(meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\" )(/head)";
```

Escape strings with \ prefix